# Converting a float to string using locale settings and forced fixed decimals

Tags: python, locale

in Python3, I need to convert a float to string using the current
locale but keeping the zeros after the delimiter,
which may be a comma.

The code

```
import locale

amt = 83.00
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'DE')
print(locale.str(amt))
```

prints

```
83
```

the required output is

```
83,00
```

How can I do this the right way using locale?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.currency? Or `.format("%.2f", amt)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `locale.currency(amt)` adds a "€" sign, so I get "83,00 €"

Comment: I had tried this before asking. After re-reading this, yes you're right. If you put this in an answer, I'll accept that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the function currency:

```
import locale

amt = 83.00
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
print(locale.currency(amt, symbol=False))
```

Output:

```
'85,00'
```

when you set the symbol flag True then you get

```
'85,00 EUR'
```